# Proving by definition that lim $1/(e^x - 1) = 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, analysis

Proving by definition that lim $1/(e^x - 1) = 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

**My answer is:** I have taken $M \geq ln (1+ (1/ \epsilon))$ am I correct?

Comment: looks fine to me, except use strict inequality

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the function is less than $\epsilon$ for $x > M$, then yes.

Comment: yes that is what I mean

Comment: in addition I assumed that $x >0$